# I need help to get this clock to refresh the time

Tags: python-3.x

I've been trying to get this program to refresh the time but cannot find away to get it to refresh.

I've tried multiple different ways to make to this script work but cannot find a way to make it refresh.

```
import datetime
import os

clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
Time = datetime.datetime.now()

def DateTime():
    print(Time)

    input("\nPress ENTER to refresh: ")
    clear()

while True:
    DateTime()
```

I expect the program to refresh the time but it doesn't, and if I knew how to fix this I would of already.

Answer (score 1):

In your code when you define the value of 'Time`, you never update it. The program keeps it binded to the initial value for the rest of it's life span.

It is never updated, what you need to do is get the latest value of time in your function so that the call to `DateTime()` would give you the latest time.

```
def DateTime():
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    input("\nPress ENTER to refresh: ")
    clear()
```

There are many things you can do in your code to achieve this, this is just one of the ways.